# Some intuitions for irreducible representations $SO(3)$ in classical physics

Tags: hilbert-space, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory, spherical-harmonics

With a very naive and intuitive understanding of representation theory, I make my point below. Feel free to correct my intuition.

In order to find out the representations of $SO(3)$ on a vector space $V$, we choose a basis set that comprises the simultaneous eigenstates, $|j,m\rangle$, of $J^2$ and $J_z$:
$$J^2|j,m\rangle=j(j+1)|j,m\rangle, \quad J_z|j,m\rangle=m|j,m\rangle$$
where $J^2$ is the Casimir operator of $SO(3)$.

> In a quantum mechanical context, the concerned vector space, $V$, is the angular momentum ket space of dimension $2j+1$ where $j$ is the total angular momentum of the system under consideration. The states $|j,m\rangle$ are states with the same total angular momentum quantum number $j$ but differing magnetic quantum number $m$ ranging from $m=-j$ to $m=+j$ in steps of one. In that case, the representation $\mathcal{D}(R)$ acts on the appropriate ket space mentioned above.

Now, I want to acquire some intuition about the relevant vector spaces $V$ in a classical context. Also, what do the basis vectors $|j,m\rangle$ in $V$ mean in a classical context? Here, is my understanding. For $j=0,1,2,...$, we are talking about the scalar, the vector, the symmetric traceless tensor, ... etc. In that case, the representation $\mathcal{D}(R)$ acts on the appropriate vector spaces mentioned above.

In particular, for $j=1$, I think of the space $V$ as the space of all ordinary vectors in 3D. In this case, I think of the basis vectors $$|1,-1\rangle, |1,0\rangle,|1,1\rangle$$ as nothing but the unit vectors $\frac{\hat{e}_x-i\hat{e}_y}{\sqrt{2}}, \hat{e}_z,\frac{\hat{e}_x+i\hat{e}_y}{\sqrt{2}}$, respectively (as ZeroTheHero and CosmasZachos pointed out).

For $j=2$, I think that the space $V$ as the space of all symmetric traceless tensors in 3D. In this case, there are five basis vectors $$|2,-2\rangle, |2,-1\rangle,|2,0\rangle,|2,1\rangle,|2,2\rangle.$$ What are they?

If I have imagined the relevant vector spaces incorrectly (in a classical context), feel free to point it out. But please avoid heavily loaded words and impenetrable notations.

Comment: Essentially everything after the quoted passage is somewhat misguided, so I think a constructive answer is going to require a bit more context in terms of how you're trying to apply representation theory to classical systems.  I'm guessing that you want to consider the spaces of tensor-valued observables, and the action of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ on those spaces. Is that correct?

Comment: If you want to study the action of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ on a classical space of *states*, then you'll strictly have to leave the domain of representation theory because the classical space of states is not a vector space. You'd be looking for a more general [group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) on the space of states.

Comment: @J.Murray "I'm guessing that you want to consider the spaces of tensor-valued observables, and the action of SO(3) on those spaces." Yes. Let me phrase it like this. The method of constructing representations using the basis $|j,m\rangle$ is valid in a non-quantum context. So in a non-quantum context, how should I think of the basis vectors and the relevant vector spaces? I am not interested in group action in the classical space of states. Sorry for using the word, "classical context".

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_basis). By "what are they", you are asking for a symmetric tensor product of the vectors you just described?  There is an obvious formula, but I'm hard pressed to provide the intuition in it you are asking for... Can you be more specific?

Comment: noooo!  $\vert 1,\pm 1\rangle$ are like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (e_1\pm i e_2)$ (or something like this; I maybe be out by some sign).  $\vert 1,0\rangle$ is like $e_3$.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Are they combinations of the tensor products of $e_i$ and $e_j$?

Comment: They are, but in the very peculiar spherical basis I referenced. The vectors you identified are off, as you may confirm. I fear you are asking about this basis without acknowledging it...

Comment: @CosmasZachos "I fear you are asking about this basis without acknowledging it." Yes.

Comment: Once you identify the basis change in the WP article for the vectors, i.e. you convert all kets in the spherical basis into the Cartesian basis, you can easily apply the same transformation to the symmetric traceless tensor product of two such vectors. First, you must correct your misidentification, since you want a correct explanation based on an error....

Comment: Thanks, for the help. Error in the identification of basis vectors is corrected.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics ("Further, spherical harmonics are basis functions for irreducible representations of SO(3), the group of rotations in three dimensions, and thus play a central role in the group theoretic discussion of SO(3).")

Answer (score 2):

The length of this answer warrants some context. In quantum theory, a system is (in part) defined by a Hilbert space $\mathscr H$, from which we define states as rays in $\mathscr H$ (or density operators on $\mathscr H$) and observables as self-adjoint operators on $\mathscr H$. We therefore wish to understand how $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ acts on $\mathscr H$, at which point we may inherit its action on states and observables.

However, quantum mechanics is somewhat mysterious, and how $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ should act on an arbitrary Hilbert space is far from obvious *a priori*. Therefore, the approach we take is to study all possible irreducible, projective representations of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, from which we can build every possible (projective) representation which we could have. This provides us with a toolkit which we could use to play with different models and see which ones are applicable to which physical systems.

In *classical* physics - at least in the sense you refer to - the situation is very different. From a certain perspective, it's upside down. Because you are interested only in the action of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ on the tensor product spaces over $V=\mathbb R^3$, we can define representations on these spaces very naturally from the fundamental representation on $V$, and so constructing representations and understanding how these tensors transform is not the problem.

Rather than building representations out of irreps, our task now is to start with a known representation and then *decompose it* into its constituent irreps. This is always possible for $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, and understanding this decomposition can provide great physical insight into our models as well.

In this answer, I will first construct the natural representation $\rho^p_q$ on the space of $(p,q)$-tensors. From there, I will discuss how such a representation may be decomposed into irreps, and how objects of the form $|j,m\rangle$ are to be interpreted.

---

The observables you are interested in are $(p,q)$-tensors over the vector space $V=\mathbb R^3$, which can be understood as linear maps
$$T :  \underbrace{V^*\times \ldots \times V^*}_{p\text{ times}} \times \underbrace{V \times \ldots \times V}_{q\text{ times}} \rightarrow \mathbb R$$
which, in a basis $\{e_i\}$ of $V$ and corresponding dual basis $\{\epsilon^i\}$ of $V^*$, has components
$$T\big(\epsilon^{\mu_1},\ldots,\epsilon^{\mu_p}, e_{\nu_1},\ldots,e_{\nu_q}\big) \equiv T^{\mu_1 \ldots \mu_p}_{\qquad \nu_1\ldots \nu_q}$$

---

**Dual Space Representation**

Given a representation $\rho:\mathrm{SO}(3)\rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$, it is straightforward to define a representation $\rho^*$ on the dual space $V^*$. Given some $\omega\in V^*$ and $v\in V$, the quantity $\omega(v)$ should be a scalar which transforms trivially under rotations; as a result, given a rotation $\mathscr R\in \mathrm{SO}(3)$ such that
$$\big[\rho(\mathscr R) v\big]^i = R^i_{\ \ j} v^j$$
for a matrix $R$, then we should have that
$$\big[\rho^*(\mathscr R) \omega\big]_j = \big(R^{-1}\big)^i_{\ \ j} \omega_i$$
Put more simply, if $\rho(\mathscr R) = R$  then $\rho^*(\mathscr R) = R^{-1}$.

---

**Tensor Representation**

From this, representations over arbitrary tensors are easy to build. For simplicity, take $T$ to be a $(1,1)$-tensor. Because $T(\omega,v)$ is a scalar, we should have that $\rho^1_1(\mathscr R)T$ is the tensor whose action is given by

$$\big[\rho^1_1(\mathscr R)T\big](\omega, v) = T\bigg(\rho^*(\mathscr R)^{-1} \omega, \rho(\mathscr R)^{-1} v\bigg) = T\bigg(\rho(\mathscr R)\omega,\rho^*(\mathscr R)v\bigg)$$

where we've used that $\rho^*(\mathscr R)^{-1} = \rho(\mathscr R)$. The reason for this is that if we transform $T$, $\omega,$ and $v$ via their respective representations, we must have that $T(\omega,v)$ doesn't change. In component form, this means that

$$\big[\rho^1_1(\mathscr R) T]^\mu_{\ \ \nu} = T\bigg(\rho^*(\mathscr R)^{-1} \epsilon^\mu,\rho(\mathscr R)^{-1} e_\nu\bigg) = T\bigg(R^\mu_{\ \ \alpha} \epsilon^\alpha, \big(R^{-1}\big)^\beta_{\ \ \nu} e_\beta\bigg)$$
$$= R^\mu_{\ \ \alpha} \big(R^{-1}\big)^\beta_{\ \ \nu} T(\epsilon^\alpha,e_\beta) \equiv R^\mu_{\ \ \alpha} \big(R^{-1}\big)^\beta_{\ \ \nu} T^\alpha_{\ \ \beta} $$

Extending this to arbitrary $(p,q)$-tensors in the obvious way, the representation $\rho^p_q$ acts (in component form) as

$$\big[\rho^p_q(\mathscr R) T\big]^{\mu_1\ldots \mu_p}_{\qquad \nu_1\ldots \nu_q} = R^{\mu_1}_{\ \ \alpha_1} \ldots R^{\mu_p}_{\ \ \alpha_p} \big(R^{-1}\big)^{\beta_1}_{\ \ \nu_1}\ldots \big(R^{-1}\big)^{\beta_q}_{\ \ \nu_q} T^{\alpha_1\ldots \alpha_p}_{\qquad \beta_1\ldots \beta_q}$$

One could write this tensor product representation as

$$\rho^p_q \equiv \underbrace{\rho\otimes\ldots\otimes \rho}_{p\text{ times}} \otimes \underbrace{\rho^*\otimes\ldots\otimes\rho^*}_{q\text{ times}}$$

---

**Irreducibility**

Now, these representations are certainly not irreducible, in general. Recall that a (non-trivial) representation is reducible if there exists any non-trivial invariant subspace of the space on which the representation acts which is left invariant under its action. Looking at the work we've done, $\rho^1_1$ is reducible because e.g. if $T^\mu_{\ \ \nu} \propto \delta^\mu_{\ \ \nu}$, then it transforms trivially.

However, it turns out that $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ is [reductive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductive_group), which means that any finite-dimensional representation can be decomposed into a direct sum of irreducible representations.  In keeping with the representation theory with which you are familiar from quantum mechanics, there is exactly one irreducible representation in $2j+1$ dimensions up to isomorphism. The $j=0$ representation is the trivial one and acts on $1$-dimensional spaces, the $j=1$ representation is the fundamental one and acts on 3-dimensional spaces, etc.

- $V=\mathbb R^3$ (which can be viewed as the $T^1_0$ tensor space) hosts the fundamental representation $\rho$, which is irreducible. The same is true of the dual space; $\rho^*$ is different than $\rho$, but they are isomorphic as representations.
- The $T^1_1$ tensor space $V\otimes V^*$ is $9$-dimensional, and can be decomposed into a 1-dimensional part, a 3-dimensonal part, and a 5-dimensional part; this is the meaning of $3\otimes 3 = 1\oplus 3 \oplus 5$. The 1-dimensional part transforms under the $j=0$ representation, the 3-dimensional part transforms under the $j=1$ representation, and the 5-dimensional part transforms under the $j=2$ representation.

---

**Casimir Elements**

Given any irreducible representation $\varrho$ of the Lie *group* $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, we can define a representation of the Lie *algebra* $\mathfrak{so}(3)$. This representation is called $\mathrm d\varrho$, and it maps any element $A\in\mathfrak{so}(3)$ to
$$\mathrm d\varrho(A) =-i\varrho\big(e^{-itA}\big)\frac{d}{dt} \varrho\big(e^{itA}\big)$$

Given a basis $J_i$ for $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ (i.e. the angular momentum operators), it turns out that
$$\Omega_\varrho := \sum_{i=1}^3\mathrm d\varrho(J_i)^2$$
is a constant which takes the value $j(j+1)$ (times the relevant identity matrix) for some integer $j$; this is the $j$ which labels the irrep. The element $\Omega_\varrho$ is called the (quadratic) *Casimir* element corresponding to the irrep $\varrho$.

The representation space on which $\varrho$ acts is $2j+1$ dimensional, and so $\varrho(J_i)$ can be represented as a $(2j+1)\times(2j+1)$ matrix. Choosing $J_3$ by convention, we may diagonalize $\mathrm d\varrho(J_3)$ and express the elements of the representation space in the corresponding basis.  The eigenvalues $m$ of $\mathrm d\varrho(J_3)$ take their values in the set $\{-j,-j+1,\ldots,j-1,j\}$, and so the basis elements of our vector space may be labeled $|j,m\rangle$.

---

**Summary**

The observables which you are interested in studying are $(p,q)$-tensors over the vector space $V=\mathbb R^3$. All such tensor spaces $T^p_q$ inherit a representation $\rho^p_q$ from the fundamental representation $\rho$ on $V$ in a natural way. However, these representations are not irreducible in general.

As per the representation theory of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ familiar from quantum mechanics, there is precisely one irrep of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ on each $(2j+1)$-dimensional vector space, up to isomorphism. The tensor space $T^p_q$ has dimension $3^{p+q}$. $T^p_q$ can be decomposed into a direct sum of $2j+1$-dimensional subspaces, and the representation $\rho^p_q$ "factors" over this decomposition. Concretely, let us take
$$V_0 = \mathrm{span}\left\{\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}\right\}$$

$$V_1 = \mathrm{span}\left\{\pmatrix{0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1\\ 0&-1&0},\pmatrix{0&0&-1 \\ 0&0&0\\ 1&0&0},\pmatrix{0&1&0 \\ -1&0&0\\ 0&0&0}\right\}$$
$$V_2 = \mathrm{span}\left\{\pmatrix{0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&1&0},\pmatrix{0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0\\ 1&0&0},\pmatrix{0&1&0 \\ 1&0&0\\ 0&0&0}, \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&0}, \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1}\right\}$$

$V_j$ is the $2j+1$ subspace of $T^1_1$ on which $\rho^1_1$ reduces to the irrep $\varrho_j$. Choosing $J_3$ by convention, we may define an eigenbasis of $V_j$ by diagonalizing $\mathrm d\varrho_j(J_3)$. Its $2j+1$ eigenvalues $m$ will be $-j,-j+1,\ldots,j-1,j$, and so we may label the basis elements of $V_j$ as $|j,m\rangle$.

In the interest of concreteness, I'll get you started on this process. Let's consider $V_2$, and let the basis written above be $v_n, n=1,..,5$. From there,
$$J_3 = \pmatrix{0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0} \qquad e^{itJ_3} = \pmatrix{\cos(t) & -\sin(t)&0 \\ \sin(t) & \cos(t) & 0 \\0&0&0}$$
$$\varrho_2\big(e^{tJ_3}\big)v_{1} = e^{itJ_3} v_1 e^{-itJ_3} = \pmatrix{0&0&-\sin(t)\\0&0&\cos(t)\\-\sin(t)&\cos(t)&1}$$
$$\mathrm d\varrho_2(J_3) v_1 = -i\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \bigg(e^{tJ_3}v_1e^{-tJ_3}\bigg) =-i \pmatrix{0&0&-1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0} = i v_2$$
and so the first column of $\mathrm d\varrho_2(J_3)$ is $(0,i,0,0,0)^T$.  Repeating this (may the gods bless computer algebra systems) yields
$$\mathrm d\varrho_2(J_3) = \pmatrix{0&-i&0&0&0\\i&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-2i&i\\0&0&2i&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0}$$
whose eigenvectors are
$$|2,-2\rangle =\pmatrix{0\\0\\i\\1\\0} \qquad |2,-1\rangle = \pmatrix{i\\1\\0\\0\\0} \qquad |2,0\rangle = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\1\\2}$$
$$|2,1\rangle =\pmatrix{-i\\1\\0\\0\\0} \qquad |2,2\rangle = \pmatrix{0\\0\\-i\\1\\0}$$

This basis spans the 5-dimensional subspace $V_2\subset T^1_1$. We can work backward to translate this back into the language of $3\times 3$ matrices; for example,
$$|2,0\rangle = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\1\\2} = v_4+2v_5 = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&0}+\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&-2}= \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-2} \in V_2 \subset T^1_1$$

Answer (score 1):

In classical mechanics, the $j=2$ representation is pretty common. I'll just show two examples of occurrence.

The most easiest example is the quadrupole. In general, the $j$ representation corresponds to the $2^j$-pole. Physically, you would see this in any filed theory with sources like electromagnetism, gravitation, acoustics etc.

In the multipole expansion of the source, you are essentially decomposing the source into irreducible representations of $SO(3)$. This boils down to the representation of $SO(3)$ in terms of spherical harmonics. While they are often presented in polar coordinates, they are easier to apprehend in cartesian form (and generalise easier in higher dimensions). The $j=2$ representation is isomorphic to homogeneous, harmonic, degree 2 polynomials. The corresponding eigenbasis of $j_z$ would be:
$$
\begin{align}
|2,2\rangle &= (x+iy)^2 & |2,1\rangle &= z(x+iy) & |2,0\rangle &= 2z^2-x^2-y^2 \\
|2,-2\rangle &=  (x-iy)^2 & |2,-1\rangle &= z(x-iy) 
\end{align}
$$
Btw, just as you can consider the $x,y,z$ basis as well as the $-1,0,1$ basis, sometimes it is more convenient to consider other basis. For example for atomic d orbitals (yes it is not an example from classical mechanics), you usually see another basis:
$$
\begin{align}
xy && yz && zx && x^2-y^2 && 2z^2-x^2-y^2
\end{align}
$$

The $j=2$ representation can also be seen in fluid dynamics and elastic theory. The strain and the strain rate tensors are already symmetric. When you look at the traceless part, this will lead to the $j=2$ representation. Physically, you are looking at the incompressible contributions. In this case, the representation is more explicitly matrices and the corresponding spherical basis is:
$$
\begin{align}
|2,2\rangle &= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & i & 0 \\ i & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} & |2,1\rangle &= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & i \\ 1 & i & 0
\end{pmatrix} & |2,0\rangle &= \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix} \\
|2,-2\rangle &= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -i & 0 \\ -i & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} & |2,-1\rangle &= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -i \\ 1 & -i & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
Similarly, the spherical basis may not be the most physically transparent. For example, the analogue of the $xy,yz,zx$ basis vectors would correspond to pure shearing and in general, the alternative basis introduced for d orbitals is more transparent as well in this context.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you have written the components instead of spherical basis vectors.

Comment: No, the polynomials written above form a basis of spherical harmonics. Check out the corresponding wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics).

Answer (score 1):

All the kets you wrote are in the [spherical basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_basis#Change_of_basis_matrix), a complex "twist" of the Cartesian basis effected by the matrix U.

So I'll stay in the spherical basis and do the tensor product in it; I'm not sure the intuition you are asking for is solidly pegged to the Cartesian basis;  but QM is taught in the spherical language, which *also* applies to all the rotation group theory of classical systems! In this basis, as you probably worked out in QM,
$$|2,-2\rangle= |1,-1\rangle\otimes |1,-1\rangle, \\
 |2,-1\rangle = \bigl (|1,-1\rangle\otimes |1,0\rangle +  |1,0\rangle \otimes |1,-1\rangle \bigr  )/\sqrt{2} \\
|2,0\rangle = \bigl (|1,-1\rangle\otimes |1,1\rangle +  |1,1\rangle \otimes |1,-1\rangle \\ +  2|1,0\rangle\otimes |1,0\rangle\bigr )/\sqrt{6},\\
 |2,1\rangle = \bigl (|1,1\rangle\otimes |1,0\rangle +  |1,0\rangle \otimes |1,1\rangle \bigr  )/\sqrt{2} \\
|2,2\rangle= |1,1\rangle\otimes |1,1\rangle.
$$

Naturally, it also applies to classical physics,
$$
Y_2^{-2}(\theta,\varphi)\propto (Y_1^{-1})^2,\\
Y_2^{-1} \propto  Y_1^{-1} Y_1^{0},\\
Y_2^{0} \propto  Y_1^{-1} Y_1^{1}+ Y_1^{0} Y_1^{0},\\
Y_2^{1} \propto   Y_1^{1} Y_1^{0},\\
Y_2^{2} \propto (Y_1^{1})^2.
$$